# docker run -v bindmount failing

Tags: selenium, docker

I am rather new to docker images and am trying to set up a `selenium/standalone-firefox` image linked to a local folder.

I'm running `Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc` on Windows 10 and have unsuccessfully tried figuring out the correct working of the `docker run -v` syntax because it either is unspecific (i.e. too little context for me to make sense of it) or on the wrong platform).

Running docker as admin the the `cmd`, I used `docker run -d -v LOCAL_PATH:C:\Users\Public`.

This throws `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \Users\Public` as an error message.

I want to bind the running container to the folder `C:\Users\Public` (or another folder on the host machine - this is for illustration purposes).

Can someone point me to the (I fear obvious) mistake I'm making? I essentially want to achieve the container's output data (for later scraping) being stored in the host machine's folder `C:\Users\Public`. The container's output folder should be named `myfolder`.

** **EDIT** **

Digging around, I found [this](https://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-file-downloads-uploads-using-docker-grids/) (see *Volume Mapping*).

I have thus tried the following code:

`>docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub`

`>docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub -v C:/Users/Public:/home/seluser/Downloads selenium/node-chrome`

while the former works fine (it only runs the container), the latter throws the error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: Drive has not been shared.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker for Windows (and Mac) require you to share drives to be able to volume mount - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/ (Under Shared drives).

You should be able to find it under your Docker Settings > Shared Drives. Ensure your C:\ is selected and restart the daemon. After that, you can run:

```
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub -v C:/Users/Public:/home/seluser/Downloads selenium/node-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

base on the documation:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

this path does not exist in container and its linux container.
"C:\Users\Public\Documents\TMP_DOCKERS\firefox selenium/standalone-firefo"

Comment: thanks - but this still throws the same error: `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \Users\Public`

Comment: following your edit: the path does exist, I created it beforehand. It is also empty (I found some information relating to that being potentially necessary). Any other ideas? The documentation didn't give me new insights unfortunately but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Your are creating the path in your host machine or your container?

Comment: in the host machine - is that wrong? and if I need to create it in the container, how would I link the _host path_ "C:\Users\Public" to the _container path_ \myfolder? [I've also updated the question to be more specific.]

Comment: when you mount with -v option the left side of colon specify the host path you wanna mount like:
C:\Users\Public\Documents
and the right side is directory that exist iside the contaner

Comment: Okay but that's what I did, correct? I can't get the two to work together. I have updated some further things I tried in the question, maybe that illuminates for you where I'm stuck?

Comment: docker on windows has extra step to share directory:
https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c
sry i dont have access to windows to test or advise a better solution